# collectstatic and DEBUG

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

When I'm developing I serve static files from my hard drive and when they're on production they're served from S3. I've achieved this through this:

```
DEBUG = False

if 'DYNO' not in os.environ:
    DEBUG = True

...

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
    STATIC_URL = BASE_DIR + '/path/to/stuff/'
else:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
```

So if this code is running on Heroku it gets from S3 or if on local it gets from `path/to/stuff`. The problem arises when I run `collectstatic`, it collects using `StaticFilesStorage` and doesn't push to S3. Would there be a way around this? Perhaps check if the code is being accessed by  the `collectstatic` command?

Answer (score 3):

You can [specify the settings file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings) to use when running any manage commands.

For example, if you have a `settings_prod.py` with the correct static files settings, then your would run:

```
./manage.py collectstatic --settings=settings_static.py
```

In your case, you might get the behaviour you want by running the collectstatic management command with the `DYNO` environment variable set (since that implies `DEBUG=False`).

```
DYNO='1' ./manage.py collectstatic
```

Alternatively, you could look for a different environment variable e.g. `COLLECTSTATIC`, and set the static files settings appropriately.

Comment: Can I append another variable? Like `./manage.py collectstatic --my_variable=True`?

Comment: No, `manage.py` does not let you define arbitrary settings like  `--my_variable=True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check hostname in `settings.py` :

```
HOSTS = ['mac.loc', 'my.dev', ...]

...

if socket.gethostname() in HOSTS:
    # local settings
    ... 
else:
    # remote settings
    ...
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem here - the OP wants to use different staticfiles settings depending on whether they are running `collectstatic`, or a different management command like `runserver`.

Comment: He can use different settings in if else block. 
if socket.gethostname() in HOSTS:
   from settings_dev import * 
else:
    from settings_prod import *